# Partition BigQuery on column using Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, partitioning

I am new to Bigquery. Can some one please help me how to partition a table on a column. 
I need to simulate below same behaviour using java.

CREATE TABLE mydataset.newtable (transaction_id INT64, transaction_date DATE)
 **PARTITION BY transaction_date**
 OPTIONS(
   partition_expiration_days=3,
   description="a table partitioned by transaction_date"
 )

Comment: What Java code did you try?

Comment: I tried to create use TimePartitioning, but didn't find any method where I can set Field. Below is snippet I tried - 

TimePartitioning timepartitioning = new TimePartitioning();
timepartitioning.setExpirationMs(100000L);
timepartitioning.setField("sessionstart");
timepartitioning.setType("DAY");
TimePartitioning tm = TimePartitioning.fromPb(timepartitioning);
But above method is not working.

Comment: I don't understand why you need that. If you are trying to create a table, just execute the query that you provided above through the query API. See [the example of running a query on Github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/65ca2f3d03d2744f59e5d4109c4efebe998a9514/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/bigquery/snippets/BigQuerySnippets.java#L710).

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Ok I can use it. And for loading data into it from file how can I do it? Can you please help in that as well.

Comment: To give you more detail on my use case..I need to autodetect schema from json and create a table with partition on a column.